# Python rounding to nearest integer without asking

Tags: python, precision

I am just trying to compute some basic arithmetic, but python won't stop rounding to the nearest integer.

For example, when I input

```html
print float(3 * 1/(1*2) + 1)
```

it outputs 2.0 rather than 2.5; I can't figure out how to keep it from rounding like this. I would appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: put brackets for python 3, otherwise it looks alright to me. However, instead of casting to float, you ca do this `print(3 * 1.0/(1*2) + 1)` with the same effect

Comment: Python 2. Integer division. 3 / 2 = 1.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `dot (.)` to indicate floating point numbers, or indicate number as float (`float(1)`)

```
>>> print (3 * 1/(1*2) + 1)
2.0
>>> print (3 * 1./(1*2) + 1)
2.5
>>> print (3 * float(1)/(1*2) + 1)
2.5
```

> In *Python 3*, `/` is float division
>
> In *Python 2*, `/` is integer division (assuming int inputs)
>
> In both *Python 2 and 3*, `//` is integer division
>
> (To get float division in Python 2 requires **either of the operands to be
>   a float**, either as `20.` or `float(20)`)

NOTE:

> in Python 2.2 - 2.7 you can do `from __future__ import division` to
>   get Python 3's behavior

Comment: It's fair to mention that in Python 2.2 - 2.7 you can do `from __future__ import division` to get Python 3's behavior.

Comment: tnx for info! :) @StevenRumbalski

Answer (score -1):

In python 2, `int/int = int`
try casting int to float

```
print float(3 * 1)/float(1*2) + 1
```

or

```
print float(3 * 1)/(1*2) + 1
```

Comment: If you don't say anything about the nature of integer division in Python 2, you haven't really helped the OP understand the issue.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I was about to edit it :)